# How to sync branches in git

Tags: git, github

Please excuse my knowledge with Git as I'm new to GitHub world. I have 4 branches namely `master, release, develop and staging.` At this point all branches are in sync, and the I made some changes to the code and pushed from `staging -> develop`

Now I realise that I need to revert those changes and they should be same as `release` branch. I'm not sure how to do that, because when I try to do that from GitHub page it says 'There isn't anything to compare' whereas I can see the difference in files.

Could someone please assist as how to synch the `staging` and `develop` with release branch.

Comment: _"At this point all branches are in sync"_ - what do you mean by this? Do all the branches point to the same commit?

Comment: Yes.. they are pointing to same commit

Comment: It would help if you explain the purpose of each of the branches. If you intend to always keep them in sync, then you only need 1 branch instead of 4. The *way* you sync branches also depends on the purpose of the branches. For example, in Git Flow, `release` is created off of `develop` and then is *merged* into `master` and also merged back to `develop`. At that point `release` and `master` are in sync (and `release` is usually deleted at that point) but `develop` and `master` are likely never in sync. In Gitworkflows, the `next` branch gets synced with `main` periodically, by using *reset*.

Comment: I think you might want to edit: "At **this** point all branches **are** in sync, and **the** I made" to "At **one** point all branches **were** in sync, and **then** I made". Also consider changing "I need to **revert** those changes" to "I need to **undo** those changes". Two different ways to "undo" are with `revert` and `reset`, and it sounds like you actually want to `reset` rather than `revert`. Which btw, probably answers your question...

Answer (score 0):

Git branches are not typically used to set up different build environments. The main purpose of a branch is to house functionality that is being worked on separate from the master branch. Eventually this functionality would be merged into master, with its source branch deleted. As such, it doesn't make a lot of sense to have every branch "synced" (which I assume means they are the same).
If you want to house different build environments, and update them as needed, you need to look into something called DevOps. It's a related but separate concept that I highly recommend you look into after getting a grasp of the Github basics.